# Batch rename with outcome of other batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file, which scans documents for a barcode, and rename the file to the barcode.

I use two batchfiles for this. One of the batchfiles (test.bat) executes the exe that scans for the barcode:

```
@echo off
zbarimg.exe --raw -D -q %1
```

In the second batchfile, I want it to scan every file in the directory with a *.tif extension, scan for the barcode, and rename it to the barcodenumber. The second batch (rename.bat) looks like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.tif') do (test.bat %%a)
```

My main question is, how can I incorporate a rename command, that renames the files to the outcome of test.bat.

In short, this is the proces:
1. there is a file called test.tif
2. the file is being scanned for a barcode (i.e. 123456789)
3. test.tif is renamed to 123456789.tif

I am wondering how I can capture the outcome of test.bat in a variable, so I can call that when I use the rename command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to capture the output from `test.bat` is the same you used to capture the output from `dir` command: via a `for /F` command.

The simplest solution is eliminate the `test.bat` file and insert the `zbarimg.exe` program in the same Batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.tif') do (
   for /F %%b in ('zbarimg.exe --raw -D -q %%a') do (
      ren "%%a" "%%b.tif"
   )
)
```

However, if you want to keep `test.bat` file, just do this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.tif') do (
   for /F %%b in ('test.bat %%a') do (
      ren "%%a" "%%b.tif"
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The awkward way cmd has to get the result into a variable is to use a FOR loop.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "BCNAME="

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.bat') do (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%b IN (`CALL wc "bc.bat"`) DO (SET "BCNAME=%%~b")
    echo REN "%%~a" "!BCNAME!.tif"
)
```

When it produces the correct REN command, remove `echo`.

Also, this makes no plan for multiple .tiff files to have the same barcode result.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably create a construction where same barcodes are renamed to _1, _2 etc.